# Passing .ASPXAuth authentication cookie using Windows.Web.Http.HttpClient

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-membership, httpclient, win-universal-app

Im trying to call a Web API to authenticate a login. This is working and the header response contains the .ASPXAuth. When I call the next method on the Web API I'm getting a 403.

To fix this, i've tried to get the .ASPXAuth authentication from the header of the auth response, and add it to the header of the next request (as seen below).

```cs
IHttpContent content = new HttpStringContent(@"{ ""domain"": ""DomainName"", ""username"": ""theUserName"", ""password"": ""thePassword"" }", UnicodeEncoding.Utf8, "application/json");

                    // Send
                    using (var client = new Windows.Web.Http.HttpClient.HttpClient())
                    {
                        var result = await client.PostAsync(new Uri("https://192.168.1.112/api/auth/login"), content);

                        result.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
                        var authResult = await result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

                        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("set-cookie", result.Headers["set-cookie"]);

                        var itemResult = client.GetAsync(new Uri("https://192.168.1.112/api/item/{110D559F-DEA5-42EA-9C1C-8A5DF7E70EF9}"));
                        var itemData = itemResult.GetResults();

                }
```

Comment: Probably the response (aka `result`) does not contain a `Set-Cookie` header. `Set-Cookie` is for requests, and `Cookie` is for responses, but the format of each header is different, and if present in the response, you will need to parse it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've fixed the issue with the below code.

Authenticate and returning the auth cookie

```
public async Task<HttpCookie> AuthenticateAsync()
{
    var filter = new HttpBaseProtocolFilter();

    using (var client = new HttpClient(filter))
    {
        var authDetails = BuildJsonAuthDetails();

        var authResult = await client.PostAsync(new Uri(BaseUrl + "/auth/login"), authDetails);

        authResult.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();

        return filter.CookieManager.GetCookies(new Uri(BaseUrl + "/auth/login")).FirstOrDefault(x => x.Name == ".ASPXAUTH");
    }
}
```

Passing the Auth cookie with the next post

```
 public async Task<string> GetUserDetailsAsync(string userUniqueIdentifier, HttpCookie authCookie)
            {
                var filter = new HttpBaseProtocolFilter();

                filter.CookieManager.SetCookie(authCookie);

                using (var client = new HttpClient(filter))
                {
                    var itemResult = await client.GetAsync(new Uri(BaseUrl + "/Person/" + userUniqueIdentifier));

                    itemResult.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();

                    return  = await itemResult.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                }
            }
```